# Syntax in FROM Clause

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access-2007

```
private void DeleteQuestion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(access7ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM Questions" + "WHERE ID=@ID", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", currentRecord);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (OleDbException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

I get this error:

`Syntax in FROM Clause`

Where am I going wrong? Still learning C#

`access7ConnectionString` is a string path to the database, I've cut it out to shorten down the post, but the connection to the database is established and it all works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no space between Table Name and WHERE, Place a space like:

```
"DELETE FROM Questions" + " WHERE
                        ///^^^
```

Not really sure why you have to use string concatenation. It all can be par to of a single string. like:

```
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM Questions WHERE ID=@ID", conn))
```

Comment: Oh, I thought for some reason you have to seperate each part of SQL. Simple, stupid mistake then. Thank you.

Comment: @zzwyb89, No you don't have to, also if you want your query to be on multiple lines than you can use [verbatim string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a space, change

```
"DELETE FROM Questions" + "WHERE ID=@ID"
```

to

```
"DELETE FROM Questions WHERE ID=@ID"
```